# JPA nullable=false column is being set to null on update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, uuid

I am trying to assign a UUID to field on insert that I do not want to changed on any updates. The insert works and the UUID successfully saves in the field. But on update the field is being set to null despite me setting `@Column(nullable=false)` upon it.

This means I am getting a

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, 2019-02-26, 1, 6, 2, 103, 3066, 12, 2021.01, AAC, IAT, 690000, 0, 4, https://photo...) Error.

I have checked and it is attempting to update and the preupdate hook will can be called.

```
@Data
@Entity
@IdClass(CarId.class)
public class Car {

  @Id
  private String date;

  @Id
  private int auctionId;

  @Id
  private int auctionNumber;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private UUID id;

  @PrePersist
  private void assignUuid() {
      this.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
  }
}
```

Car Id looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CarId implements Serializable{
    private String date;

    private int auctionId;

    private int auctionNumber;
}
```

I would like the same UUID to not be changed on any updates.

Comment: Setting `nullable=false` only affects DDL generation. If the value is null on update then it can only be because you are inadvertently setting it to null so the  pertinent code would seem to be that which updates and saves the existing entity.

Comment: Would setting `updatable = false` be a way of not inadvertently setting it to `null`.

Comment: A better solution would be to understand the actual problem and fix it.